# c# regex spain mobile phone

Tags: c#, regex

what would be a valid regex for these rules:

```
34 6xx xxx xxx 
34 7yx xxx xxx
(note y cannot be 0 (zero))
```

would this one work?

```
34(([6][0-9]{8}$)|([7][1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$))
```

Comment: Does it work as you want? Simply try it out!

Comment: You can use [regexr](http://regexr.com/) to test it

Comment: I don't understand why this question gets downvotes: it's clear what OP wants to match, and also what he has tried, so voting it down six(!) times seems like too much to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression should work, assuming that you are not expecting it to handle spaces.

You can further optimize your regex by extracting the common suffix of `[0-9]{7}` from it:

```
^34(?:6[0-9]|7[1-9])[0-9]{7}$
```

If you would like to account for optional spaces, insert `\s?` into your regex in places where you wish to allow space characters to be inserted:

```
^34\s?(?:6[0-9]|7[1-9])[0-9]\s?[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{3}$
```

Comment: Mind that `\s` can also match a line break, and some other whitespace characters, not only a space.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle this specific format with spaces, you can use

```
^34 ?(?:6[0-9]{2}|7[1-9][0-9])(?: ?[0-9]{3}){2}$
```

See [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E34%20%3F(%3F%3A6%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C7%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D)(%3F%3A%20%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D)%7B2%7D%5Cr%3F%24&i=34%20611%20222%20333%0D%0A34%20734%20455%20444%0D%0A34%20704%20455%20444&o=m)

**REGEX EXPLANATION:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `34 ?` - 34 followed by an optional space
- `(?:6[0-9]{2}|7[1-9][0-9])` - A group of 2 alternatives: `6` can be followed by any 2 digits, and 7 can be followed only by non-0 and one more digit
- `(?: ?[0-9]{3}){2}` - 2 groups of 3 digits, optionally separated with a space
- `$` - End of string.

Comment: As always, I using RegexStorm for C# regex demos, and for demo purposes I am using a multiline option that requires adding a `\r?` before the `$` end of string symbol. Do not pay attention, in real situation, you will only need the version published here, without `\r?`. **If you have any doubts, please feel free to ask**.